# why do I get the error, "TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' "

Tags: string, printing, int

I'm asking user for number of problems and number of digits
Trying to print say 5 problems with 4 digits
Output should look like this:
1234 + 2345 say 5 times with 4 digits(random numbers)  I will be writing to file

code:

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

```
sOp is a string = ['+', '-', '/', '*']
index = 0
for n in range(numProb):
    for d in range(digits):
        if index < len(sOp):
            print(getNumber(digits), + sOp[index], + getNumber(digits), end='')
            index +=1
    print()
```

Comment: What is your program language?

Comment: I am using the Python language